# How do I define a Storyboard and Animation on a template in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation, storyboard

I have a button template on which I wish to define a Storyboard animation ( correctly; right now it's done in the code behind on the object but I want to scrap that and do it straight in XAML )

Given the following stub :

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:FooBar="clr-namespace:Foo.Bar">
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type FooBar.MyButton}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border x:Name="Border"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Where would I put this storyboard?

```
<Storyboard x:Key="SBOpac">
    <DoubleAnimation 
        Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
        From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.3"/>
</Storyboard>
```

I have tried both the `ControlTemplate.Resources` and `Border.Resources` but in both cases I get this exception :

[image]

Here I try and start the storyboard in the code behind:

```
((MyButton.Template.FindName( "Border", GB) as Border)
        .Resources["SBOpac"] as Storyboard)
        .Begin( MyButton, true );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put your storyboar inside your `ControlTemplate` as long with what triggers the animation :

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard >
                                    <DoubleAnimation   
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                        From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.3"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Border x:Name="Border" Background="Black"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

    </Style>
```

Comment: Okay, thanks. Now what would I do if I wanted the storyboard to trigger on some other user event - not just the mouse entering? For example, if the button had a custom property that could be set to True or False, how would I make it so that the storyboard would play when it was True and stop when it was False?

Comment: In that case simply use a DataTrigger that point to that property instead of an EventTrigger, and put your storyBoard inside the EnterActions , something like that 
 <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding YourProperty}" Value="YourValue">
                                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard >
                                           .....

Comment: Awesome thanks very much for your help. I'll try and implement it tomorrow.